# Why can't I use objects created on stack for upcasting?

Tags: c++, object, upcasting

Is this an upcast or not? If not, please describe why. Thanks in advance.

C++ code:

```
Base base;
Derived derived;
base = derived; // is this the upcast?
```

Comment: It's not an upcast because that's how C++ works.  You're attempting to stuff 10 pounds of potatoes into a 5 pound bag.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, because you're not assigning a pointer or a reference, you're trying to assign an actual instance. That is, you're trying to copy the content of `derived` into the memory where `base` exists. What you'll end up with is slicing, only copying the contents of the `Base` part of `derived`.

This should be covered in any decent C++ book.

Answer (score 1):

Not really.

An implicit "upcast" can be some thing like

```
Derived derived;
Base& base = derived;
```

Note that `Base&` is not another `Base` object, but a **reference** to some other `Base` (the one contained in `derived`)

What you did, in fact is creating **another** **Base** and copying in it that **Base** sub-component of **derived**.

That still requires an implicit upcast, but from then on, your `base` is not anymore related to `derived`